# Why is node process running in systemd service not stopping when the service is stopped

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, systemd

I'm trying to run **node** (**v18.16.0** installed as snap) as a systemd service
in **ubuntu 22.04**.

I've managed to get the service to run the node script,

the problem is that when I stop the service, the node process is not stopped (which prevents the service from working when I start it again).

How can I run the node application from a shell script in a systemd service?

I've got a shell script to run the node script (this is a simplified version):

```
#!/usr/bin/sh -x

node /home/bariks/PeerJS/peerjs.server.js
```

to execute the node app,

and a service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=PeerJS Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=bariks
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/home/bariks/PeerJS/peerjs.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service WORKS, the problem is that when I stop the service, the node process is not stopped (which prevents the service from working when I start it again).

If I execute the node directly from the service file, then it WILL stop when the service it stopped..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 1):

Your unit file is calling a launcher process which launches your node server and exits cleanly. You are not providing systemd with any information about how to kill the process that was created by your launcher. You have two options to resolve this issue:

1. Start your process directly: Don't use the shell script at all, directly put `/usr/bin/node whatever.js` as the ExecStart command
2. Notify systemd of your intent to fork: In your javascript process, write your process ID to file (i.e. /run/peerjs/peerjs.pid) and adjust your service file to replace/include:

```
...
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/peerjs/peerjs.pid
ExecStartPre=mkdir /run/peerjs
ExecStartPre=chown bariks /run/peerjs
...
```

For reference: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html